# penalty functions for optimisation

Tags: r, excel

I am wondering if anyone here know how to solve the problem below by R or Excel Solver? 
the question is : by using an external penalty function , find the solution to the NLP

```
max 20x+16y-2x^4-y^2-(x+y)^2
s.t  x+y≤4
     x≥0
     y≥0
```

by using a sequence of sub-problems?
Thanks

Comment: With such a small feasible space you could just discretize it and exhaustively find the minima.

Comment: Maybe packages `alabama`, `glmc` ?  I suspect other optimizer packages have constraint capabilities but haven't looked closely.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `optim` for this with a parametrization that forces `x` and `y` to be positive while adding the remaining constraint inside the objective function:

```
f <- function(z) {
    x <- exp(z[1])
    y <- exp(z[2])
    if (x + y > 4) -Inf else 20*x+16*y-2*x^4-y^2-(x+y)^2
}
out <- optim(c(0, 0), f, control = list(fnscale = -1))
```

giving

```
> exp(out$par) # x and y
[1] 1.071826 2.928174
> str(out)
List of 5
 $ par        : num [1:2] 0.0694 1.0744
 $ value      : num 41.1
 $ counts     : Named int [1:2] 127 NA
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:2] "function" "gradient"
 $ convergence: int 0
 $ message    : NULL
```